# NSUnknownKeyException Causing Crash on Button Click

Tags: iphone

So I'm not sure what is going on. I haven't really changed much. Nothing having to do with this class anyways. It was working fine just a bit before and now I'm getting this crash.

```
-(IBAction)mphButton:(id)sender{
    if(self.mphVC == nil){
        MphViewController *mph = [[MphViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MphView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.mphVC = mph;
        [mph release];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.mphVC animated:YES];
}
```

The thread is stopping saying "Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT" on the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.mphVC animated:YES];`

This is what the message:

```
2011-09-29 10:59:03.557 SpeedClock[2973:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MphViewController 0x4b42ad0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key count.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f16313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc24e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00794677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x007945e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x0021030c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d388cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x0020ed23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x00210ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x000c6628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    10  UIKit                               0x000c4134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    11  UIKit                               0x000c400e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    12  UIKit                               0x000c2482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000d2f25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    14  UIKit                               0x000d1555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    15  UIKit                               0x000d2870 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    16  UIKit                               0x000cd32a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    17  UIKit                               0x000d4562 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    18  UIKit                               0x000cd1c4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    19  SpeedClock                          0x00002621 -[RootViewController mphButton:] + 353
    20  UIKit                               0x000144fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    21  UIKit                               0x000a4799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    22  UIKit                               0x000a6c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    23  UIKit                               0x000a57d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    24  UIKit                               0x00038ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    25  UIKit                               0x00019c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    26  UIKit                               0x0001ef2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffb992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00da3944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00d03cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffa1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffa289 GSEventRun + 115
    35  UIKit                               0x00022c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    36  SpeedClock                          0x00001f59 main + 121
    37  SpeedClock                          0x00001ed5 start + 53
    38  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

I can read these pretty well on Logcat on android. Just not use to reading this one. I saw another post saying that their class might not have been connected to their view. Mine is. It was working just fine prior to me putting in some stuff (which I recommented out and it still isnt working) on the MPHViewController.m

Any and all help is appreciated... Thanks :)

Comment: And how is `mphVC ` declined?

Comment: @Nekto Sorry still new to Obj C. You asking how I have it set up if so this is the Root.h files `@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    MphViewController *mphVC;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) MphViewController *mphVC;
-(IBAction)mphButton:(id)sender;
@end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have something in your "MphView" XIB file called "count" that you no longer have in MphViewController.  Maybe a delegate set for an object that's no longer there, or an action, or something like that. Check all your connections in Interface Builder and remove any broken ones.

Comment: Nice eye. I had changed something and I had looked over the xib file with the ones I had recently messed with and I forget to look at the pcount one which I did change and forgot to fix. Do you mind telling me where you were able to spot that in that trace so I know how to find it next time? Thanks again

Comment: Nevermind I see where it is. Thanks again. It's working great again.

Comment: Yeah, it's the "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key count" part.  I've run into it many times, very frustrating until I figured out what it actually means.